# Hyperledger Fabric : Register and enroll new peer identity using fabric-ca-client (Javascript)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In the documentation of fabric-ca there is only CLI description of identities creation,

using the nodejs module "fabric-ca-client" we can register and enroll new user using:

```
fabric_ca_client.register({enrollmentID: 'user1', affiliation: 'org1.department2', role: ''}, admin_user);
fabric_ca_client.enroll({enrollmentID: 'user1', enrollmentSecret: secret});
```

but what about peers and order ? I can't find any documentation about that.