# Hyperledger Fabric: What's the relationship between MSP and Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

For [BYFN](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html), If the network is started with `./byfn.sh -m up`. How is MSP work without CA containers?

Answer (score 4):

Please consider to take a look on my previous answer for ["What is the difference between MSP and Fabric CA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682958/what-is-the-difference-between-msp-and-fabric-ca)" first.

Now to expand a bit on this:

> For BYFN, If the network is started with ./byfn.sh -m up. How is MSP work without CA containers?

In build your first network example, used `cryptogen` tool which primarily used in testing and demo scenarios to quickly setup crypto materials required to initialize the MSP, basically it generates certificates needed to operate network entities. Therefore there is no actually need to use Fabric-CA, however there is a different [example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/fabric-ca) which I advise you to explore which make use of Fabric-CA as well instead of relying on `cryptogen`.

Comment: Thanks Barger, it's quite helpful.