# Hyperledger fabric understanding MSP

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want to clear in my mind the use of a MSP,

So my question is when a user wants to use a channel for any reason, the local MSP provide him an identity with his private key (in docs said the MSP has a keystore) and after the channel confirm the user using the channel MSP?

When CA involved to?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682958/what-is-the-difference-between-msp-and-fabric-ca